# Binary to Decimal only using for or while loops

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, binary, decimal

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Question1
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    int n=0;
    int dec = 0;

    String binary; 

    char binaryNb; 


    System.out.println("Enter a binary number");  
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    binary = userInput.nextLine();

    binaryNb = binary.charAt(n);

    while(n<binary.length())
    {
      binaryNb = binary.charAt(n);

      if(binaryNb == '1' || binaryNb == '0')
      {
        n++;
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("I said a binary number !");
        Scanner userInput1= new Scanner(System.in);
        binary = userInput1.nextLine();     
      }
    }

    for(dec = 2; n == binary.length(); )
    {

   }
  }
}
```

Hi, I'm trying to create a code so that Java keeps asking me for a binary number and when he has it, he converts it into the corresponding decimal. I'm struggling with the part where I have to translate the binary into a decimal..

I have to use a while or a for loops .. I can't use other more sophisticated tools.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Try this class:

```
    public class Question1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

     System.out.println("Enter a binary number");  
     Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
//      String binaryString = args[0];
     String  binaryString = userInput.nextLine();
     int decimalValue =0;

    int length = binaryString.length();
    int j = 0;

    for (int i=0; i< binaryString.length(); i++)
    {
    j <<= 1;
    if (binaryString.charAt(i)== '1')
    {
    ++j;
    }else{
          System.out.println("I said a binary number !");
        return;
    }
    }

    decimalValue = j;   

    System.out.println(decimalValue);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I can't make it work, should I put it in my for loop ?

Comment: Updated answer. This is another approach which should give you the expected output.